# Solving Recurrence Relations 'Chip & Conquer'

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I've been tasked with solving some recurrence relations, and I've been running into trouble with so called 'chip & conquer' relations.

Here are some example problems:

$$T(n) = T(n-5) + cn^2$$

and

$$T(n) = T(n-2) + \log{n}$$

I'm supposed to be giving an answer in $\Theta$ notation. How do I go around and solving relations like these?

Answer (score 4):

For simplicity, let's assume that $5$ divides $n$
and that $n/2=n-5k$ for some integer $k>0$.

$$ \begin{align*}
   T(n) &= T(n-5) + cn^2 \\
   T(n) &= cn^2 + c(n - 5)^2 + c(n - 10)^2 + c(n - 15)^2 + ... + c5^2 + c0^2 \\
        &= c(n^2 + (n - 5)^2 + (n - 10)^2 + (n - 15)^2 + ... + 5^2 + 0^2) \\
      &\ge c(n^2 + (n - 5)^2 + (n - 10)^2 + (n / 2)^2)
       \ge c(n / 2)(1 / 5)(n / 2)^2) \\
        &= cn^3 / 40
         = (c / 40)n^3 \\
        &= \Omega(n^3) \\
   T(n) &= cn^2 + c(n - 5)^2 + c(n - 10)^2 + c(n - 15)^2 + ... + c5^2 + c0^2 \\
      &\le c(n / 5)n^2
       \le cn^3 \\
        &= O(n^3) \\
\end{align*} $$

We conclude that $T(n) = \Theta(n^3)$.

---

Let's assume for simplicity that $n/2 = n-2k$ for an integer $k>1$.

$$ \begin{align*}
   T(n) &= T(n-2) + \log n
         = \log n + \log(n - 2) + \log(n - 4) + ... + \log(4) \\
      &\ge \log n + \log(n - 2) + \log(n - 4) + ... + \log(n / 2)
       \ge (n / 2)log(n / 2) \\
        &= \Omega(n \log n) \\
   T(n) &= T(n-2) + \log n
         = \log n + \log(n - 2) + \log(n - 4) + ... + \log(4) \\
      &\le (n / 2) \log n \\
        &= O(n \log n) \\
\end{align*} $$

We conclude that $T(n)=\Theta(n \log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the recurrence and sum it up.

Example 1:

$$ \begin{align*}
  T(n) &= T(n-5) + O(n^2)
        = T(n-10) + O(n^2)
        = \dots \\
       &= T(0) + \{\text{\(n/5\) terms, each \(O(n^2)\)}\}
\end{align*} $$

Now let's say $T(0) = c$. This would be generally given in the question.

so this would sum to $(n/5).O(n^2) = O(n^3)$

Example 2:

$$ \begin{align*}
  T(n) &= T(n-2)+\log n
        = T(n-4)+\log(n-2) + \log(n)
        = \dots \\
       &= T(0) + \log(n-2^k) + \dots + log(n)
        = c + \log(n-2^k) + \dots + \log(n-2) + \log(n) \\
       &= c + n \log(n)
\end{align*} $$

Comment: It was supposed to be +cn^2 not =cn^2. Silly typos!